# Tab-Content Layout shows up in other tab

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Spring-Boot application using Thymeleaf.  Bootstrap4 is the CSS framework I'm using.  I'm using nav-tabs for the profile page and the first three tabs don't have any issues but when I click on the address tab and go to any other tab, the content of the Address tab, shows up in the other tabs at the bottom of that tabs content and I cannot figure out why. I'll be including images of the outcome and css of each starting tab. I am hesitant to include the entire page html due to the amount of lines currently (480 total)

[image: Billing Tab Image]

[image: Address Tab Image]

[image: Address tab showing up at bottom of Billing tab]

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-3" role="tabpanel" th:classappend="${classActiveBilling}? 'in active show'">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <h4 class="mb-0 align-middle" style="margin-top: 15px;">Billing Information</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="breadcrumb" style="background-color:transparent;">
                <a class="breadcrumb-item active" th:href="@{/listOfCreditCards}" th:style="${listOfCreditCards}? 'color:#6e45e0'">List of Credit Cards</a>
                <a class="breadcrumb-item active" th:href="@{/addNewCreditCard}" th:style="${addNewCreditCard}? 'color:#6e45e0'">Add/Update Credit Card</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

```html
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-4" role="tabpanel" th:classappend="${classActiveShipping}? 'in active show'">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <h4 class="mb-0 align-middle" style="margin-top: 15px;">Shipping Information</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="breadcrumb" style="background-color:transparent;">
                    <a class="breadcrumb-item active" th:href="@{/listOfShippingAddresses}" th:style="${listOfShippingAddresses}? 'color:#6e45e0'">List of Shipping Addresses</a>
                    <a class="breadcrumb-item active" th:href="@{/addNewShippingAddress}" th:style="${addNewShippingAddress}? 'color:#6e45e0'">Add/Update Shipping Address</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: According to the behavior, my guess is that the `.active` class does not get cleared from the last tab. What classes `#tab-4` has in that strange state?

Comment: Whenever classActiveShipping is appended using thymeleaf notation, the classes active and show are appended as well which is needed for the nav-tab function to work.

Comment: I will have to double check what classes are active on that page when I get home and will update it the post of necessary. It may be my backend that is causing the issue as I don't have that issue in the login/sign up section of the site that uses a similar setup.

Comment: I'm not familiar with thymeleaf, but from Bootstrap perspective all tabs are visible in the same time that have `.active .show` set. When navigating away from a tab, Bootstrap removes these two classes from that. I assume, this removal fails in this case. This is just a wild guess though.

Comment: Unfort in order for the nav tabs to work they have to be appended when that tab becomes active by thymeleaf instead of the normal css means.  Tried it without it and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breadcrumbs were the culprit.  It was causing the shipping tab to show up in other windows.  I just changed it to a button group and get the same effect. I unfortunately could not get the breadcrumbs themselves to work regardless of how many times I worked on the css so just threw it out completely.  Semi answer, but thymeleaf is touchy and doesn't always play nice with frameworks.